# Get closest textbox value by class name in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following html structure. When I click any button i need to get closest(single) textbox value by `class` name. I am using [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) of `jQuery` API.

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group col-sm-12">
    <input type="text" class="cls1" value="1" /> 
    <input type="text" class="cls2" value="2" />  
    <button class = "btn" >button</button>           
</div>

<div class="input-group col-sm-12">
    <input type="text" class="cls1" value="1" /> 
    <input type="text" class="cls2" value="2" />  
    <button class = "btn" >button</button>           
</div>
<div class="input-group col-sm-12">
    <input type="text" class="cls1" value="1" /> 
    <input type="text" class="cls2" value="2" />  
    <button class = "btn" >button</button>         
</div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    // this is not working.
    console.log($(this).closest('.cls1:first').val());
})
```

Please advise.

Comment: `alert($(this).prev().val());`

Comment: `$(this).parent().find('.cls1').val()` try this one

Comment: I think this would work too `$(this).siblings('.cls1').val()`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a sibling element so use `.siblings()`. `.closest()` is used to find the first matching ancestor element.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {

  console.log($(this).siblings('.cls1:first').val());
  // Its not working
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group col-sm-12">
  <input type="text" class="cls1" value="1" />
  <input type="text" class="cls2" value="2" />
  <button class="btn">button</button>
</div>

<div class="input-group col-sm-12">
  <input type="text" class="cls1" value="1" />
  <input type="text" class="cls2" value="2" />
  <button class="btn">button</button>
</div>
<div class="input-group col-sm-12">
  <input type="text" class="cls1" value="1" />
  <input type="text" class="cls2" value="2" />
  <button class="btn">button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Same thoughts i gave in OP's comment, but i did'nt use `:first` but its okay though, cool. :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need prev to get the first textbox before the button. Closest is used to get the parent not the sibling.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r69sgupm/)**

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){    
    alert($(this).prev().val());       
})
```

Its worth understanding the difference between `closest()` and `prev()`

[closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> For each element in the set, get the first element that
>   matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up
>   through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

[prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

> Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of
>   matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).parent().find('.cls1').val());
    // Its not working
})
```

try this approach

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/92aazaLy/)